# Multivariable Limit Prob

Tags: limits, multivariable-calculus

$$\lim\limits_{(x,y) \rightarrow (0,0)} \frac{e^{xy}-1}{y}$$

I tried to prove that the limit DNE, but have not been able to because all the limits approaching (0,0) from different paths seem to go to the same number.

I have only learned techniques used to take limits of composite functions and plugging in x=0 and y=0 does not work either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The expression isn't even defined along  the x axis. However if you define the function to be $x$ on the $x$ axis, then the resulting function is continuous everywhere has a limit of zero at the origin. (This is similar to how you 'fix' $\sin(x)/x$ by defining it as $1$ at the origin.)